# Remove simplex from scipy Delaunay triangulation

Tags: python, scipy, delaunay

I have a set of points, from which I calculate a Delaunay triangulation using the scipy.spatial.Delaunay function. Something along the following for example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

tri = Delaunay(np.random.rand(10,2))
```

What I want to do after this is calculated is remove a simplex. Is there an easy way to do this? I notice the Delaunay object has a method for `add_point` but nothing for `remove_point` or `remove_simplex`.

The way I see it, I have two options. I know the list of points myself so I simply remove the necessary points and re-calculate the Delaunay triangulation. I hope to avoid this as it can become inefficient if I have to re-calculate a lot for a lot of points. The other option I can see is to directly edit the object parameters myself, but this seems like a potentially dangerous method. Does anyone have any suggestions of a better method?

Comment: What are you using the `Delaunay` object for?

Comment: @ali_m For generating polygonal meshes (potentially in high dimensions). I create a baseline mesh using Delaunay triangulation, but I then need to adjust the mesh by doing things like moving vertices around or removing simplexes.

Comment: I guess my question is which methods of the `Delaunay` instance still need to work correctly after you've removed simplices?

Comment: Not 100% sure yet, but at the very least, I need the information stored in it. However I expect I'll eventually need information like the paraboloid scale and shift or the convex hull.

Answer (score 3):

The Delaunay result is a numpy object.You can choose the simplex you need.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.random.rand(30,2)
tri = Delaunay(points).simplices.copy()

plt.triplot(points[:,0], points[:,1], tri, linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()

tri_another = tri[0:10,:]
print(len(tri))
print(len(tri_another))
plt.triplot(points[:,0], points[:,1], tri_another, linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]